# Sublime Text 2: How do I turn off auto-insert of {} during Ruby string interpolation?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2, shortcut, string-interpolation

When typing inside double-quotes in a Ruby file, Sublime automatically adds `{}` as soon as you type a `#`. This is a huge hassle and confuses the bejeezus out of me. How do I make it stop?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently the `auto_match_enabled` setting controls this behavior, and not the visual underline behavior, which is in fact controlled by the `match_brackets` setting.

Comment: `auto_match_enabled` is a sublime behavior that automatically inserts the matching bracket when one is typed.  The `sublime-keymap` I mention in my answer checks to make sure that `auto_match_enabled` is set to `true` in your `Default` or `User` settings.  You very likely do not want this functionality disabled system wide.

Comment: I disabled it, and it's been great so far!

Comment: That is ancillary to your original question, though.  Disabling a system-wide behavior which indirectly solves your question is not the optimal way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `/Packages/Ruby` directory there is `Default.sublime-keymap` file which contains a small snippet that inserts the pair or curly brackets after `#` is pressed within an string that can be interpolated, ie double quotes. Just comment this out to solve your problem.